# Javascript trying to get the ID of the image which the mouse moves over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the id of the image the mouse hovers. But I do not understand how to get the ID. Can some one help me :). TY!

```
function placeImage(x){
var div = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images
for (var i =0; i <= x; i++) {

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.className += " Atributes";
image.src="images/foto_klein_"+i+".jpg";
image.width="135";
image.height="90";
image.alt="foto_klein_"+i;
image.id="image"+i;
image.position="relative";
div.appendChild(image);
image.style.marginRight = '10px';
_img.push(image);

}
};
```

With the placeImage function i place the images. Now I want to add an mouse event and change the class of the image who is targeted.

```
<div id="thumbnails" onmouseover="mouseOver(this);" ></div>
```

I added a mouse over to all the thumbnails. But I cannot get the id of the image of which the mouse hovers. I want to call the id or change the image.className of that particlair image. But I do not know how to call it. Now it only alerts "thumbnial"

```
function mouseOver(e){
 alert(e.id);
}
```

Comment: Uh yes, because you are binding `mouseover` to the `<div>` and not the image.

Answer (score 7):

Use `this` keyword:

```
<div id="thumbnails" onmouseover="mouseOver(this);" ></div>

function mouseOver(e){
   alert(e.id);
}
```

**Edit from the comments**:

```
var image=document.createElement("img");
   image.className += " Atributes";
   image.src="images/foto_klein_"+i+".jpg";
   image.width="135";
   image.height="90";
   image.alt="foto_klein_"+i;
   image.id="image"+i;
   image.mouseover = mouseOver;
   image.position="relative";
   div.appendChild(image);
   image.style.marginRight = '10px';
   _img.push(image);

}
```

Note the `mouseOver` function being called when the image is hovered.  `this` will refer to the image element and not the div.

Comment: Yes thank you tried that already, but did not posted it. But the alert returns "thumbnails".
And the images are nested inside the thumbnials. So how can i access them?

Comment: @user2072498 it returns thumbnails because that is the id.

Comment: @DarrenDavies he wants the `id` of `<img>` inside the said `<div>` I guess.

Comment: @DarrenDavies This has nothing to do with the images. The OP is trying to get the `id` of the image that is hovered over (which happens to be a child/descendent of that thumbails div)

Comment: @Ian - xFortyFourx - Yes I understand that now, however in his original question it was not clear and he described that he wanted the id of the element that was hovered over.

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted because the OP has updated his post using my code and requested something else.....

Comment: @DarrenDavies Actually yeah it should be. That's the point - your original code didn't work as they wanted (for whatever reason), so the OP is trying to work with you to figure it out. Until you update it and get it to work, there's no reason to upvote it. StackOverflow isn't some static website that you can't update

Comment: @Ian - I wrote an answer based upon the OP's original question.  If I supply a valid answer that answer should not be downvoted if the OP decides to ask for something different.

Comment: Haha, but I want to return the image.id and not the id of the whole thumbnail
     image.id="image"+i;
which I assigned inside the for loop. is that not possible?

Comment: @user2072498 - yes.  Where you create the img element, add the mouseover event onto it: image.mouseover = mouseOver;

Comment: And sorry, i did not know that i could not update my post. maybe I was a bit unclear about my question.

Comment: @user2072498 I have updated my answer - this should now work to your requirements.

Comment: @DarrenDavies True, but I wasn't here when the question was asked and when you answered it. I came in late. I saw things didn't match. It's not up to me to go into the Edit histories of the question/answer and figure out how I should vote. Nonetheless, the point is that things change and you are welcome to accommodate (like just did with your edit), so I'd be happy to change my vote now because it seems right.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `id` of an image when you hover over it, try this:

```
function placeImage(x){
    var div = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
    div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images
    for (var i =0; i <= x; i++) {
        var image=document.createElement("img");
        image.className += " Atributes";
        image.src="images/foto_klein_"+i+".jpg";
        image.width="135";
        image.height="90";
        image.alt="foto_klein_"+i;
        image.id="image"+i;
        image.position="relative";
        image.onmouseover = mouseOver;    // <-- Added this
        div.appendChild(image);
        image.style.marginRight = '10px';
        _img.push(image);
    }
}

function mouseOver(e) {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps, though I'm not sure about it working on a dynamically added image.

```
document.ready = function () {
    var thumbnails = document.getElementById("thumbnails");

    var imgs = thumbnails.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for( var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++ ) {
        imgs[i].onmouseover = function() {
            alert( this.id );
        }
    }
};
```